# intro to programming c++ cout + str.length

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string creditcard, numdigits, wait;
    cout << "Welcome to the Credit Card Number Decoder!\n\n";
    cout << "Please enter a credit card number:\n";
    cin >> creditcard;
    cout << "The card number length is: ";
    numdigits = creditcard.length();
    cout << numdigits << endl;
    cout << "\nenter any key to quit:  ";
    cin >> wait;

    return 0;
}
```

```
Welcome to the BIN  Validator!
Enter your credit card to verify your bank:2323232321
10
enter any key to quit:
```

I'm hitting my head against a wall, trying to figure why I'm not getting `cout << "The card number length is: ";`

The rest of the assignment focuses on indexing the first 4 digits of the string and using `if`, `if else` statements.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to compile because there's a missing semicolon after `length()`.

Comment: I wrote an Answer pointing out that you mustn't assign an integral value -- like the one returned by `length()` -- to a string like `numdigits`. I then deleted it, because it raised a lot of further questions I found I couldn't answer. But the point remains. Use something like `string::size_type numdigits`, not a `string`.

Comment: The output shown does not match the code shown

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/z5h4hY)

Comment: @n.m. You perfectly reproduced a newline when entering a string that is 10 characters long. This code outputs the length of a string as ASCII-code, not as a number.

Comment: @csabinho Posted code should print "The card number length is: ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that you defined `numdigits` as a string and the value of the first index of this string will be the length of the string, but of course `cout` will output it as an ASCII-code. You will have to change `numdigits` to `int` to get the correct result!